# What is the best way to write if else condition for 3 Boolean variable

Tags: bash

I have 3 boolean variables a,b and c. what's the best way to write the if else condition(or some better way) in bash to cover all combinations (refer pic).

for example: a=y,b=y and c=y then echo `foo`

[image]

I can write multiple elseif conditions but is there any alternate way?

Comment: Look into using [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to simplify Boolean functions like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure of what you're expecting precisely, but if you need to check every possible combination, and your variables can only have two values: `y` or `n`, then you can use a `case` statement:

```
case "$a$b$c" in
    yyy) echo bar ;;
    yyn) echo foo ;;
    yny) echo foo ;;
    ynn) echo foo ;;
    nyy) echo bar ;;
    nyn) echo foo ;;
    nny) echo foo ;;
    nnn) echo foo ;;
    *) echo error; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do it with an associative array:

```
declare -A arr=(
   [yyy]=foo
   [ynn]=bar
   [yyn]=bar
   [nyn]=bar
   [nyy]=foo
   [nny]=bar
)

echo ${arr["$a$b$c"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will normally encounter 8 cases but if those 6 are all you face, then you can try something like

```bash
if [[ $b && $c]];
then
  echo foo;
else
  echo bar;
fi
```

This will work because regardless of what `a` holds, the result `foo` is *y* **only if** `b` and `c` are *y* (True). The rest are just `boo`. *If you want more accurate boolean expression you can try using "k-maps".*

Answer (score 1):

```
case $a/$b/$c in
    [ny]/y/y)       echo foo ;;
    [ny]/[ny]/[ny]) echo bar ;;
    *)              echo error; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

By adding a separator string (the `/` in `$a/$b/$c`), invalid input such as `a=yyy b= c=` will be rejected as an error.